# How to add data in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a while loop from which I'm Fetching Name from database, How can I add all the name fetched from database into that array

Here is How I fetch Name From Database

```
<?php $a = mysqli_query($connecDB, "SELECT * FROM video WHERE post_id='$puser'"); 
while( $b = mysqli_fetch_array($a)){?>
              name: <?php echo $b['name'];?><br>
              <?php } ?>
```

This Results in

```
name: example1
name: example2 & so on......
```

i want to put all these name into array like this->

```
array("example1", "example2", "example3");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to create a new array variable and assign value to that array varaible like below:-**

```
<?php 
$new_array = array(); // create an empty array variable
$a = mysqli_query($connecDB, "SELECT * FROM video WHERE post_id='$puser'"); 
while( $b = mysqli_fetch_array($a)){
             $new_array[] = $b['name']; // assign value to array
}
echo "<pre/>";print_r($new_array); // print array
?>
```

**output should be look like what you want:- array("example1", "example2", "example3");**

Answer (score 2):

You can push the results into an array. Try this:

```
$names = array();
while( $b = mysqli_fetch_array($a)) {
    array_push($names, b['name']);
}
```

This will push to the $names array and `$names` will look like this:

```
array("name1", "name2", "name3");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
while( $b = mysqli_fetch_array($a)) {
    $name[]=b['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<?php 
    $names = array(); // create an empty array variable
    $a = mysqli_query($connecDB, "SELECT * FROM video WHERE post_id='$puser'"); 
    while( $b = mysqli_fetch_array($a)){
                 **array_push($names, b['name']);** //USE PUSH TO ADD VALUES AND THIS WILL AUTOMATICALLLY SEPARATE WITH A ","
    }
    echo "<pre/>";print_r($new_array);
    ?>
```

Comment: if you could describe your answer a little bit with some words, it would be more useful